# sqlite3 close returns error code 5

Tags: c, sqlite

While closing sqlite3 using sqlite3_close function it returns error code 5 
5 - database file is busy. How to fix this issue.

Comment: Yes.calling sqlite3_finalize() before sqlite3_close() did the trick.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [`sqlite3_close` documenation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/close.html) states it clearly:

> Applications must finalize  all prepared statements and close all BLOB handles associated with the sqlite3 object prior to attempting to close the object. If sqlite3_close() is called on a database connection that still has outstanding prepared statements or BLOB handles, then it returns SQLITE_BUSY.

Answer (score -1):

Answer is in the question, see if you are accessing the db externally.

Comment: No i'm not accessing it externally. But I have opened in DB in two different function f1() and f2(). for insertion and when sqlite3_step() is done while doing sqlite3_close() it always returns busy from both f1() and f2()

Comment: Check out this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964207/sqlite-exception-sqlite-busy