# Not inserting rows in sqlite database in iOS

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, insert

I have a method intended to insert in my sqlite database from a custom object:

```
- (void)insertCustomEntity:(CustomEntity *)customEntity
{
   NSString *filePath = [FileMngr copyDatabaseToDocuments];

   sqlite3 *database;

   if (sqlite3_open([filePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
       const char *sqlStatement = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Entities (id, type, timestamp, result) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

        NSLog(@"Could not prepare statement: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

       if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
           sqlite3_bind_int(compiledStatement, 1, customEntity.id);
           sqlite3_bind_int(compiledStatement, 2, customEntity.type);
           sqlite3_bind_int64(compiledStatement, 3, customEntity.timestamp);
           sqlite3_bind_int(compiledStatement, 4, customEntity.result);
       }

          if(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_DONE) {

          }
          else {
             NSLog(@"Step: %d\n", sqlite3_step(compiledStatement));
          }
       }

       sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
   }

   sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

I've been doing tests for a while and data was being inserted, but suddenly it stopped to do and I'm now getting a 5 step code at my second `NSLog`. Why does this happen, if it was working previously? I tried several options I found in some posts, like placing the `sqlite3_step(compiledStatement)` inside the `sqlite3_prepare_v2` but I keep being unable to insert. What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: are u geting any type of error message after putting NSLog(@"%s",sqlite3_errmsg(database)); and put the same statement in else part and check the error message

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but it looks like some of your braces are mis-matched? Anyways, error code 5 indicates that your database is locked.

http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html

Check if something else is accessing your database ( or your database is not getting closed in some situation in which case your code needs to change). Try the following solution to resolve it :-

[sqlite3 database is getting locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288551/sqlite3-database-is-getting-locked)