# Objective-C SQLite - SQLITE_BUSY

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I have a database layer, when I have it on AppDelegate, it works perfectly.

When I take that layer in my ViewController, it returns the error SQLITE_BUSY, my database is locked.

I run sqlite_exec with args "BEGIN EXCLUSIVE TRANSACTION" and after sqlite_step(STATEMENT) I run sqlite_exec with args "COMMIT TRANSACTION"

Thanks in advance for any help.

- I searched for a problem similar to mine but none of the solutions solved my problem.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964207/sqlite-exception-sqlite-busy

Comment: as I said, I haven't found the solution here on stackoverflow

Comment: as you wrote, you can use sqlite in appdelegate and not in viewcontroller, maybe because appdelegate locks that sql?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964207/sqlite-exception-sqlite-busy](http:////http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964207/sqlite-exception-sqlite-busy) This link is informative. Have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm managing existing code, so I cant switch. But If you wana switch and still work in sql fmdb (https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) is a good alternate.

I've fixed my problem by adding following lines after using db. You should never forget to close the connection.

```
          sqlite3_finalize(statement);
          sqlite3_close(contactDB);
```