# Sqlite database is locked and database is busy Issues

Tags: iphone, database, sqlite, prepared-statement

Database is locked: Is this only comes due to not finalised or close Db statements missing?.
                    Actually I am using db access in background as well so my  some other methods can be access db at same time.

Can anyone please let me know when **Database is locked** and when **database is busy** issues comes.?

My prepared statements is execute and not an error in database but still unable to get data?

Any Help?

Comment: Are you trying to read a database from somewhere else than your application?

Answer (score 2):

Database is Locked error comes when you are using the same database in some place else maybe another application by getting the lock on it and the application is still not released the lock on database.

I dont know about database is busy error. this link might answer your question [SQLite Exception: SQLite Busy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964207/sqlite-exception-sqlite-busy)

Hope it somehow helps you.

Answer (score 0):

The sqlite_busy can come in these cases
1. When one thread has locked a database using BEGIN and another thread is trying to write to the same database.
2. When a particular row is being updated by one thread and the same row is being read by another thread.

In both the cases install a busy handler to the database. The busy handler should attempt the execution of the statement after few milliseconds.