# SQLITE_BUSY when inserting within for-loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I have the following code which should insert data into a table in my .sqlite file. `capturedImages` is an array of images that, because of its size, **I cannot pass in as the whole array** with NSKeyedArchiver, etc. as I've seen many people using on this site. `m`,`alb`, `dateString`, and `user` are objects containing other information that needs to be passed in.

Because of this, I'm simply trying to pass in each image and the appropriate data using a for-loop. The code snippet in question:

```
NSString *momentInsertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO MomentTbl (momentID, albumID, title, timestamp, author, latitude, longitude, canvas, burst) VALUES (NULL, %d, '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', ?, '%d')", alb.ID, alb.title, dateString, user, m.latitude, m.longitude, burstID];
const char *query_stmt = [momentInsertSQL UTF8String];

NSData *imageData = nil;

for(int i = 0; i < [capturedImages count]; ++i){
    imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([m.moment objectAtIndex:i], 1.0);
    if (SQLITE_OK == sqlite3_open(dbPath, &db)) {

        if(SQLITE_OK == sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query_stmt, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL)) {

            sqlite3_bind_blob(sqlStatement, 1, [imageData bytes], [imageData length], NULL);

            //perform sql call
            int res2 = sqlite3_step(sqlStatement);
            if(res2 == SQLITE_OK){
                NSLog(@"Sucessful insert");
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"Insert-error #%d: %s", res2, sqlite3_errmsg(db));
            }
        }

        else {
            NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement");
        }
        sqlite3_close(db);
    }

    else {
        NSLog(@"Could not open database");
    }

}
```

I have already verified that the open, prepare_v2, and bind_blob statements work as they should. When I try to insert using `sqlite3_step(sqlStatement)`, I get the following message:

`Insert-error #5: database is locked`

Googling this tells me that this code, SQLITE_BUSY, occurs when the file is locked by another process. However, I'm not sure what would be locking it or how to prevent this from happening. Can someone shed some light on the situation?

Comment: Gasp!  You're really doing open/close on every iteration?  (While failing to finalize the prepared statement?)

Comment: (The lock issue is very likely the failure to finalize.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964207/sqlite-exception-sqlite-busy