# sqlite DB is shows SQLITE_BUSY after the getting sqlite3_last_insert_rowid() objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I am trying to insert a member in sqlite DB member table. After inserting values if I take sqlite3_last_insert_rowid() I can't insert another member. the statement shows SQLITE_BUSY.Here is my code. Please anybody help.

```
-(NSInteger) saveMember:(TMMember *)member {
const char *dbPath = [databasePath UTF8String];
if (sqlite3_open(dbPath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into members (memberName, memberAmount,shareFlag) values(\"%@\", \"%f\",%d)",member.memberName,member.amount,[[NSNumber numberWithBool:member.shareFlag]intValue]];
    const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert_stmt,-1, &statement, NULL);
    if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
    {
        NSInteger lastRowId = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);
        member.memberId = lastRowId;
        NSLog(@"inserted member id = %ld",lastRowId);
        NSLog(@"member is added");
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    statement = nil;
}
sqlite3_reset(statement);
sqlite3_close(database);
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Why not using some ObjectiveC libraries for SQLite ? https://github.com/ogres/SQLiteDatabase-class-for-iOS-Objective-C   or https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964207/sqlite-exception-sqlite-busy

Comment: @LalKrishna please check the posted date. I found answer long time back.

Comment: I know, this is for googlers. I found this question on google, there is no answer, and i have to research more. So I guess this may help someone.

Comment: Post this in answer @LalKrishna

Answer (score 1):

This error is getting when sqlite already processing another statement, and you are trying to execute another one. So the db is locked until you finalise the statement.

For more info. Read: [SQLite Exception: SQLite Busy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/964772/4061501)