# Asynchronous HTTP-requests on sqlite database in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, sqlite

I'm currently trying to to test a little server with multiple asynchronous HTTP-requests, however my sqlite3 database seems to block simultaneous queries issuing `SQLITE_BUSY`.

```
db.exec(query, (err) => {
    if (err !== null) {
        callback('Insertion failed.');
    } else {
        callback(null);
});
```

Is there a way to circumvent this problem using the sqlite3 module?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems to be a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964207/sqlite-exception-sqlite-busy

Comment: Not really sure how I can proceed from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you just use async.queue?

```
var async = require('async');

var q = async.queue(function(task, callback) {
    db.exec(task.query, function(err) {
        callback('Insertion failed.');
    });
    callback();
}, 1);

q.drain = function() {
    console.log('queue is empty, ready for more query');
};

q.push({query: "Your SQL INSERT query"}, function(err) {
    console.error(err);
});
```