# The database file is locked (database is locked)?

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

I am doing a update, delete and create of events in my Calendar. I have many methods. However, if i try to run any of them, it gives me SQLITE BUSY Error. I have closed the connection after every methods. So what could be the problem? I know I have too many connections, but i did close them.

```
    public static DatabaseConnection db = new DatabaseConnection();

public static ArrayList<EventModel> retrieveAllInfo() {
    ArrayList<EventModel> listOfEvents = new ArrayList<EventModel>();

    ResultSet rs = null;

    String dbQuery;

    db.getConnection();
    dbQuery = "SELECT * FROM ToDoList";

    rs = db.readRequest(dbQuery);
    try {
        while (rs.next()) {
            EventModel model = new EventModel(); 
            model.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
            model.setEventName(rs.getString("eventName"));
            model.setDate(rs.getString("day"));
            model.setTime(rs.getString("time"));
            listOfEvents.add(model);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    db.terminate(); 
    return listOfEvents;
}

public static boolean updateEvent(EventModel eventmodel) {
    //declare local variables
    boolean success = false;
    String dbQuery; 
    PreparedStatement pstmt;

    db.getConnection();     

    dbQuery = "UPDATE ToDoList SET eventName = ?, time = ?, day = ? WHERE id = " + eventmodel.getId();
    pstmt = db.getPreparedStatement(dbQuery);

    try {
        pstmt.setString(1, eventmodel.getEventName());
        pstmt.setString(2, eventmodel.getTime());
        pstmt.setString(3, eventmodel.getDate());
        if (pstmt.executeUpdate() == 1)
            success = true;
        pstmt.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    db.terminate();

    return success;
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964207/sqlite-exception-sqlite-busy

Comment: Some other process has a lock on your database.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen may i know how to check where is the lock?
I have never come across database locking before

Comment: Well, could it be another Java process which is still running in the background?