# I don't know Why I'm getting Sqlite Busy Error

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, database, sqlite

I successfully updated sql data by following codes.

```
app.get('/courtInfo/:courtName',async function(req,res){
    let db = await getDBConnection();
    let rows = await db.all('select * from courts');   
    
    const name = req.params.courtName;

    const newPlayerNum = req.query.playerUpdated;
    const newIsPickup = req.query.isPickup;

    if(typeof newPlayerNum!=='undefined'&&newPlayerNum!=''){
        var newsql = 'UPDATE courts SET currentNum = ? WHERE court_name = ?';
        db.run(newsql,[newPlayerNum,name],function(err){
            if(err) return console.log(err);
        });        
    }

    if(typeof newIsPickup!=='undefined'&&newIsPickup!=''){
        var newsql = 'UPDATE courts SET is_pickup = ? WHERE court_name =?';
        db.run(newsql,[newIsPickup,name],function(err){
            if(err) return console.log(err);
        });   
    }
    await db.close();

.....
```

But when I tried like this, I got Sqlite Busy error.

```
app.post('/newCourtAdded', upload.single('courtImg'),async function(req,res){
    let db = await getDBConnection();
    let rows = await db.all('select * from courts'); 
    const newCourtId = rows[rows.length-1]+1;
    const newCourtName = req.body.courtName;
    const newCourtNum = req.body.courtNum;
    const newCourtIsWater = req.body.isWater;
    const newImagePath = req.file.originalname;
    
    console.log(newCourtName, newCourtNum, newCourtIsWater, newImagePath);
    var newSqlite = 'INSERT INTO courts (court_id, court_name, court_image, is_water, is_pickup, court_num, currentNum) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)';
    var newValue = [];

    newValue.push(newCourtId);
    newValue.push(newCourtName);
    newValue.push('/image/'+newImagePath);
    newValue.push(newCourtIsWater);
    newValue.push(0);
    newValue.push(newCourtNum);
    newValue.push(0);

    db.run(newSqlite,newValue,function(err){
        if(err){
            return console.log(err);
        }else{
            db.close();         
        } 
    });
    
     
    res.redirect("http://localhost:3000");
   
});
```

I think they have same logic, I mean, **open database -> make dataSet -> change and save database -> close database.**

I don't know Why the former one is successful and the other is not. Could you please teach me why?

Comment: From what I've been able to find, this means some other process has the database locked. I don't think it has anything to do with the form of the code here, it's just timing.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964207/sqlite-exception-sqlite-busy. It's for Objective C, but since this is happening in the DB I don't think the language is significant.

Comment: I solved the problem, but still I don't know how to solve it... I just changed some order and restarted my computer, and then it suddenly worked